# Replace specifc text inside a tag using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm new in regex and I did not understand the documentation of regex. I would like to ask for help on how to replace specific text inside JavaScript alerts.

```js
alert("$xx this some text")
```

or

```js
alert("this some test $xx")
```

or

```js
alert("this some $xx test")
```

or

```xhtml
<pre>
  <p>$xx - this should not be replaced this is inside a div or a p tags</p>
  <script>alert("$xx - this should be replace")</script>
</pre>
```

I'd like to replace `$xx` with `$yy`. [Here](http://regex101.com/r/tS2tQ6/1) is a demo what I want to do.

Comment: so you want replace `$xx` to `$yy` only if it's present inside the alert function.

Comment: Note: `preg_replace` is PHP, `alert` is JavaScript. Don't mix up different languages

Comment: @msrd0 The HTML code may be in a template that's being processed (as a string) through PHP; it's very common to modify/parse/populate the HTML prior to sending to the client (so `preg_replace()` may be exactly what's needed here... unless they're doing *client-side* template building of course)

Comment: actually, I just want the regex. because I have 1900+ files needs to be edited using fnr.exe

Comment: @newfurniturey It would be a good idea if the OP would clarify, but I read the question as he wants to replace it in JavaScript

Comment: @msrd0 - I just want the regex so that I can replace $xx to $yy if its only present inside the javascript alert function

Comment: @Newbie1234,  check out my answer.  I gave you examples for both PHP and JavaScript that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To find a sequence like `$xx`, you could use this regex:

```
\$xx
```

In JavaScript, this could look like this:

```js
var text = "$xx";
document.write("text before regex: " + text + "<br>");
document.write("text with regex:   " + text.replace(/\$xx/g, "this text was inserted by the regex") + "<br>");
document.write("text after regex:  " + text + "<br>");
```

Of course you can use `alert` instead of `document.write`, I just used it here because the Code Snippet can demonstrate that better.

Comment: but the $xx is replaced also even outside alert()

Comment: This does not meet the OPs needs.

Comment: @Newbie1234 Now it isn't anymore

Comment: @jbarker2160 Thanks for the comment, I think the OP already told me

Comment: @msrd0,  it wasn't really directed at you.  Just information.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm allowed to post a link but this is the code that I'm trying to work on

http://regex101.com/r/tS2tQ6/1

the $device_mf inside alert is what I'm trying to change using RegEx

Comment: @Newbie1234 In this case you have a PHP **VARIABLE**, so this variable should exist. What should _`$device_mf`_ be? And if you want I can include your link in your question

Comment: @msrd0 `$device_mf` could be any value. sure, you can include my link. this is my first regex `\(.*(<\?php.*echo.*\$.*\?>).*\)` it matches alert() but I want only the `$device_mf`

Comment: @Newbie1234 How about forgetting regex in your case and write sth like `<? $device_mf = "device_mf's value"; ?>`? This will be automatically parsed by your server, and any other version will not work in your case

Comment: @msrd0 I'm going to change server so I will not be using php any more. thats why I want to replace the `$xx` to `$yy`

Comment: @Newbie1234 Okay, but then please forget the `<?` and `?>` tags in your code, and the `echo` statement too, and change it to js. Then come back with some code that is replaceable.

Comment: @msrd0 I can do that but its 1900+ php files its hard to do it manually, so i use a program to read the file and scan then find base on the regex and replace to js

Comment: @Newbie1234 Then good luck, I won't provide the whole program

Comment: @msrd0 tnx. I already made a program, just the regex I need to make it work.